# How to read a file in a different directory in Julia?

Tags: csv, file, directory, julia

Parameters: I'm in directory named `algorithm` and this algorithm is in a parent directory called `src`. There is another directory called `data` that is also in the `src` parent directory. E.g. the relative path of `data` is `src/data` and the relative path of `algorithm` is `src/algorithm`. There is also an `info.csv` file in the `data` directory.

If I wanted to read the contents of `info.csv` in a program currently located in the `data` subdirectory, how would I do that? Doing something like `CSV.File("..//data//info.csv"; delim = ";")` does not appear to be working.

Comment: `CSV.File("../data/info.csv"; delim = ";")` - you need `" "` around the path and single `/` not double `//`

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Unfortunately, that still did not work.

Comment: Also, for a os-independent way, use `joinpath`

Comment: Are you on Windows? I think @PrzemyslawSzufel's solution is the correct syntax for Linux/Mac but on Windows I think it might be different? I am on Linux so can't test but looks like there are good suggestions here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/windows-file-path-string-slash-direction-best-way-to-copy-paste/29204/4

Comment: Krish is using unix style path so I assumed Linux or mac

Comment: Yes, I am on Mac OS. Absolute paths work, but I cannot get a relative path working when I want to use a file in a different directory (that is outside the current source file directory).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a REPL-notebook style workflow why not utilise the functionality of the REPL:

```
; # To enter shell mode 
mv /your/path/file /destination/path/file #or cp if you want a copy 
# backspace to return to Julia REPL
```

Answer (score 0):

The relative path in `CSV.File("..//data//info.csv"; delim = ";")` is interpreted relative to the *current directory* path, set by the shell/OS. If you want it to be interpreted relative to the path where the script happens to be located (i.e. the `algorithm` directory), you can explicitly do that using `@__DIR__`:

> `@__DIR__` -> AbstractString
>
> Expand to a string with the absolute path to the directory of the file containing the macrocall.

```
csvfilepath = joinpath(@__DIR__, "..", "data", "info.csv")
CSV.File(csvfilepath; delim = ";")
```